# How to get the difference between two arrays of objects based on key properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have two array of objects like this .

```
 Array1=[
   { value: "0", display: "Jamsheer",desc:"maths" },
   { value: "1", display: "Muhammed",desc:"science" },
   { value: "2", display: "Ravi",desc:"english" },
   { value: "3", display: "Ajmal",desc:"english" },
   { value: "4", display: "Ryan",desc:"english" }
   }];

   array2=[
   { value: "0", display: "Jamsheer",desc:"maths" },
   { value: "1", display: "Muhammed",desc:"science" },
   { value: "2", display: "Ravi varma",desc:"english" },
   { value: "3", display: "Ajmal",desc:"english and tamil" },
   { value: "4", display: "Ryan",desc:"english" }
   }];
```

here i have to compare display and desc based on value

expected Ouput:

```
final_output=[
{ value: "2", display: "Ravi varma",desc:"english" },
{ value: "3", display: "Ajmal",desc:"english and tamil" }

];
```

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal effort in resolving your own issue. We're not a freelancing website. Show some code. Read: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

```
const final_output = array2.filter(el => {
  const otherEl = Array1.find(x => x.value === el.value);
  return el.display !== otherEl.display || el.desc !== otherEl.desc;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches to this.

As objects' keys are alphabetically sorted, we can compare their stringified versions.

```js
const final_output = Array1.reduce((unique, entry) => {
  const isDuplicate = array2.some(object =>
    JSON.stringify(object) === JSON.stringify(entry)
  );

  if (!isDuplicate) unique.push(entry);

  return unique;
}, []);
```

Or we can iteratively look through each of their properties.

```js
const final_output = Array1.reduce((unique, entry) => {
  const isDuplicate = array2.some(object =>
    Object.keys(object).every(key => object[key] === entry[key])
  );

  if (!isDuplicate) unique.push(entry);

  return unique;
}, []);
```

Some methods to know:

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - reduces an array to a single result (useful when combining operations or otherwise chaining methods for performance reasons)
- [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) - compares two arrays and checks if the callback is true for all entries (useful for checking for exact matches as we do for objects)
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - compares two arrays and checks if the callback is true for any entries (useful to check for any match like we do for duplicates)